# Sequelize - How to include new attribute in query result?

Tags: node.js, graphql, sequelize.js

I am using `"sequelize": "5.3.0"` in NodeJS and would like to calculate the distance upon GraphQL request and return it in the query result.

I've calculated distance and added it in attributes like below:

```
export async function getJobsNear(parentValue,
  { latitude = 0, longitude = 0, radius = 0 }, { auth }) {


  const location = models.sequelize.literal(`ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${ latitude } ${  longitude })')`);
  const pickupLocation = models.sequelize.literal(`POINT(pickup_latitude, pickup_longitude)`);
  const distance = models.sequelize.fn('ST_Distance_Sphere', pickupLocation, location)


  return await models.Job.findAll({
    attributes: {
      include: [[distance, 'distance']]
    },
    where: models.sequelize.where(distance, {[models.Sequelize.Op.lte]: radius}),
    logging: console.log
  })
}
```

When I add `distance` field in the query, it fails:

```
{
  jobsNear(
    latitude: "0"
    longitude: "0"
    radius: "1000"
  ){
    id
    title
    pickup_latitude
    pickup_longitude
    distance    <-- I want this field to be returned
  }
}
```

Currently, it returns with the following error output:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Cannot query field \"distance\" on type \"job\". Did you mean \"est_distance\"?",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 7,
            "column": 5
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I get the calculated `distance`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. The error indicates that the field you are requesting (`distance`) doesn't exist. You need to add the field to your schema before it can be queried. I'm not sure how your resolver code is relevant to that issue.

Comment: @DanielRearden`distance` field is not in table and dynamically generated.

Comment: If you're using a library or framework to generate your schema, you should edit your question, specify what library and provide the relevant code.

Comment: @DanielRearden its npm 'sequelize' package.

Comment: Sequelize doesn't generate a GraphQL schema. Like I said, you need to add the `distance` field to the appropriate type in your GraphQL schema.

Comment: @DanielRearden I already tried to add it to GraphQL schema. When I checked the sql query in console.log, distance was there. But in GraphQL playground, it returned null.

Comment: It seems Sequelize returns instance only rather than including added attributes.